# MongoError: Connection Closed By Application using node.js driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Hi guys, need some help , have a problem when run this code :**

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school',function  (err,db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var query = {};
    var cursor = db.collection('students').find(query);
        cursor.each(function  (err,doc) {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(doc==null) return db.close();
            //Processing doc to update
            db.collection('students').update({"_id":doc["_id"]},{$set:{"scores":doc.scores}},function  (err,result) {
                if(err) throw err;
            });
        });
```

**it works, but then appear this message =(:**

```
MongoError: Connection Closed By Application
```

Comment: did you try debugging your source code and find out exactly which line throws the error? To me it seems like you got an db.close() in your code. and in some situations it might be executed. However, your code doesn't stop the next loop from running which will still use the closed db object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school',function  (err,db) {
if(err) throw err;
var query = {};
var cursor = db.collection('students').find(query);
    cursor.each(function  (err,doc) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(doc==null) return db.close();
        //Processing doc to update
        db.collection('students').update({"_id":doc["_id"]},{$set:{"scores":doc.scores}},function  (err,result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            db.close(); //this line was missing!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry wrongly down voted, Moderators please remove that downvote. Thanks.